# Access the value of a member expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

If i have a product.

```
var p = new Product { Price = 30 };
```

and i have the following linq query.

```
var q = repo.Products().Where(x=>x.Price == p.Price).ToList()
```

In an IQueryable provider, I get a MemberExpression back for the p.Price which contains a Constant Expression, however I can't seem to get the value "30" back from it.

**Update**
I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)GetRootConstantExpression(m);
var fi = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
var val = fi.GetValue(((ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression).Value, null);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can compile and invoke a lambda expression whose body is the member access:

```
private object GetValue(MemberExpression member)
{
    var objectMember = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));

    var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);

    var getter = getterLambda.Compile();

    return getter();
}
```

Local evaluation is a common technique when parsing expression trees. LINQ to SQL does this exact thing in quite a few places.

Comment: Get this error Expression of type 'System.Double' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object' when it resolves to a double as in the example i used.

Comment: Had to add: 
var expression = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));  in the first line of the function to fix the above error with double conversion!

Comment: Ah yes, I sometimes forget you have to be explicit with expression trees where C# is implicit (like conversions). I'm glad this works for you.

Comment: **Note:** If you have a **parameterless expression** `expr` of type `Expression<Func<T>>` (for example `expr` is containing the expression `() => myObj`), then the one-liner `object exprValue = expr.Compile()();` does the trick. Cast it afterwards to the type you require. Useful in some scenarios.

Answer (score 41):

```
 MemberExpression right = (MemberExpression)((BinaryExpression)p.Body).Right;
 Expression.Lambda(right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: Fastest, most concise way of getting the result.

Comment: Cant believe something that involves `DynamicInvoke` can be *fastest* @iggymoran did you test it? Or you meant quickest to type? ;)

Comment: Quickest to type and easiest to understand exactly what's going on. DynamicInvoke ends up using reflection to execute it and isn't the fastest thing in the world. Bryan Watts' answer gets around this issue by getting a func and executing that (just with an invoke). When I first came around this answer, it was just easier to understand what was going on.

Comment: I would've given you +10 if I could :) fantastic

Answer (score 30):

The constant expression is going to point to a capture-class generated by the compiler. I've not included the decision points etc, but here's how to get 30 from that:

```
var p = new Product { Price = 30 };
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate = x => x.Price == p.Price;
BinaryExpression eq = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;
MemberExpression productToPrice = (MemberExpression)eq.Right;
MemberExpression captureToProduct = (MemberExpression)productToPrice.Expression;
ConstantExpression captureConst = (ConstantExpression)captureToProduct.Expression;
object product = ((FieldInfo)captureToProduct.Member).GetValue(captureConst.Value);
object price = ((PropertyInfo)productToPrice.Member).GetValue(product, null);
```

`price` is now `30`. Note that I'm assuming that `Price` is a property, but in reality you would write a `GetValue` method that handles property / field.

Comment: If you had another level of nesting in the Object would anything change? eg. p.Product.Price

Comment: @Schotime - indeed it would. To handle this in a generic way, see `Evaluate` and `TryEvaluate` here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/ServiceModel/Client/ProtoClientExtensions.cs

Comment: @MarcGravell Which is faster: Compiling a `MemberExpression` then evaluating it, or reaching its `PropertyInfo/FieldInfo` then evaluating it as in `TryEvaluate`?

Comment: @AshrafSabry that depends how many times you are doing it, and whether you are reusing the delegate

Answer (score 7):

## As of 2020

This helper method will gracefully retrieve any expression value, without "compiling hack" :

```cs
public static object GetMemberExpressionValue (MemberExpression expression)
{
    // Dependency chain of a MemberExpression is of the form:
    // MemberExpression expression
    //    MemberExpression expression.Expression
    //        ... MemberExpression expression.[...].Expression
    //            ConstantExpression expression.[...].Expression.Expression <- base object
    var dependencyChain = new List<MemberExpression>();
    var pointingExpression = expression;
    while (pointingExpression != null)
    {
        dependencyChain.Add(pointingExpression);
        pointingExpression = pointingExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }

    if (!(dependencyChain.Last().Expression is ConstantExpression baseExpression))
    {
        throw new Exception(
            $"Last expression {dependencyChain.Last().Expression} of dependency chain of {expression} is not a constant." +
            "Thus the expression value cannot be found.");
    }

    var resolvedValue = baseExpression.Value;

    for (var i = dependencyChain.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var expr = dependencyChain[i - 1];
        resolvedValue = new PropOrField(expr.Member).GetValue(resolvedValue);
    }

    return resolvedValue;
}
```

`PropOrField` class :

```cs
public class PropOrField
{
    public readonly MemberInfo MemberInfo;

    public PropOrField (MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        if (!(memberInfo is PropertyInfo) && !(memberInfo is FieldInfo))
        {
            throw new Exception(
                $"{nameof(memberInfo)} must either be {nameof(PropertyInfo)} or {nameof(FieldInfo)}");
        }

        MemberInfo = memberInfo;
    }

    public object GetValue (object source)
    {
        if (MemberInfo is PropertyInfo propertyInfo) return propertyInfo.GetValue(source);
        if (MemberInfo is FieldInfo fieldInfo) return fieldInfo.GetValue(source);

        return null;
    }

    public void SetValue (object target, object source)
    {
        if (MemberInfo is PropertyInfo propertyInfo) propertyInfo.SetValue(target, source);
        if (MemberInfo is FieldInfo fieldInfo) fieldInfo.SetValue(target, source);
    }

    public Type GetMemberType ()
    {
        if (MemberInfo is PropertyInfo propertyInfo) return propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        if (MemberInfo is FieldInfo fieldInfo) return fieldInfo.FieldType;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you had a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and an instance of the object:

```
var myItem = new Item { Id = 7 };
```

You can get the value of Id using an Expression using the following code:

```
Expression<Func<Item, int>> exp = x => x.Id;
var me = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
var propInfo = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
var myValue = propInfo.GetValue(myItem, null);
```

myValue will contain "7"

Comment: `value` is a reserved identifier

Comment: @NickGallimore thanks, good spot! I've updated the example accordingly to remove this

Answer (score 2):

Using `Expression.Lambda(myParameterlessExpression).Compile().Invoke()` has several drawbacks:

- `.Compile()` is *slow*. It can take multiple milliseconds to complete even for small expression fragments. The `Invoke`-call is super-fast afterwards though, takes only few nanoseconds for simple arithmetic expressions or member accesses.
- `.Compile()` will generate (emit) MSIL code. That might sound perfect (and explains the excellent execution speed) but the problem is: That code takes up memory, **which can not be freed before the application finishes**, even when the GC collected the delegate-reference!

One can either avoid `Compile()` altogether to avoid these issues or cache the compiled delegates for re-using them. [This](https://github.com/Miaplaza/expression-utils) little library of mine offers both *interpretation* of `Expressions` as well as *cached compilation*, where all constants and closures of the expression get replaced by additional parameters automatically, which are then re-inserted in a closure, which is returned to the user. Both processes are well-tested, used in production, both have their pros and cons against each other but are well over 100x faster than `Compile()` - and avoid the memory leak!

Comment: compiled delegate and associated code are garbage collected

Answer (score 1):

`q` is of type `List<Product>`.  The List doesn't have a Price property - only the individual Products.

The first or last Product will have a price.

```
q.First().Price
q.Last().Price
```

If you know there's only one in the collection you can also flatten it using Single

```
q.Single().Price
```

Comment: Yes but `.ToList()` on the end makes it into a list.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a List or an IQueryable, you can still use First, Last, or Single - but make no mistake, `repo.Products.ToList()` is definitely a List

Comment: You are correct Kobi. I know all about this stuff as *I* am indeed trying to parse the expression tree. Just a little more complex.

Comment: Ok I now see what you are / were trying to achieve, I didn't understand that from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the following:

```
var price = p.Price;
var q = repo.Products().Where(x=>x.Price == price).ToList()
```

Comment: This will work, however it would be great if this didn't need to happen. Does Linq-2-Sql support the syntax I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

And what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Because to access the value of `Price`, you'd have to do something like:

```
var valueOfPrice = q[0].Price;
```

Comment: i'm trying to pass the expression into plain text, and need to evaluate the p.Price into "30"