# How to compile an Expression down to the actual result?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, expression-trees

I am building an API around a web service call using Expressions to allow a developer to specify a query and have an ExpressionVisitor convert the Expression into the query string.  The request is XML with a particular element containing a query string.

For example, I can do something like this which will retrieve all checking accounts with a bank name of Bank 1 or Bank 2:

"bankname = 'Bank 1' or bankname = 'Bank 2'"

The web service can handle significantly more complex queries but I'll just stick with this for now.

So I have a class CheckingAccount:

```
[IntacctObject("checkingaccount")]
public class CheckingAccount : Entity
{
    [IntacctElement("bankaccountid")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [IntacctElement("bankname")]
    public string BankName { get; set; }
}
```

And an ExpressionVisitor whose primary function is to convert an expression like this:

```
Expression> expression = ca => ca.BankName == "Bank 1" || ca.BankName == "Bank 2"
```

into the query: "bankname = 'Bank 1' or bankname = 'Bank 2'"

This isn't so tough.  Where things start to break down are when I introduce local variables:

```
var account = new CheckingAccount { BankName = "Bank 1" };
string bankName = "Bank 2";

Expression> expression = ca => ca.BankName == account.BankName || ca.BankName == bankName;
```

I know how to deal with a simple local variable (ie. string bankName = "Bank 2") but dealing with a the other type (var account = new CheckingAccount { BankName = "Bank 1" }) is much more complex.

At the end of the day these are the big issues that I need to figure out how to deal with right now.  I know there are much more complex scenarios but I'm not so concerned with those at the moment.

Here is my expression visitor (please note the generic constraint on method CreateFilter):

```
internal class IntacctWebService30ExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly List _Filters = new List();
    private IntacctWebServicev30SimpleQueryFilter _CurrentSimpleFilter;
    private IntacctWebServicev30ComplexQueryFilter _CurrentComplexFilter;
    private MemberExpression _CurrentMemberExpression;

    public string CreateFilter(Expression> expression) where TEntity : Entity
    {

        Visit(expression);

        string filter = string.Join(string.Empty, _Filters.Select(f => f.ToString()).ToArray());
        return filter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                _CurrentComplexFilter = new IntacctWebServicev30ComplexQueryFilter { ExpressionType = node.NodeType };
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Equal:
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
            case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                _CurrentSimpleFilter = new IntacctWebServicev30SimpleQueryFilter { ExpressionType = node.NodeType };
                break;
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var attr = node.Member.GetAttribute();
        if (attr != null)
            _CurrentSimpleFilter.FieldName = attr.FieldName;
        else
            _CurrentMemberExpression = node;

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        object value = Expression.Lambda>(node).Compile().Invoke();

        string fieldValue = extraxtFieldValue(value, node);

        _CurrentSimpleFilter.FieldValue = fieldValue;

        if (_CurrentComplexFilter != null)
        {
            if (_CurrentComplexFilter.Left == null)
            {
                _CurrentComplexFilter.Left = _CurrentSimpleFilter;
            }
            else if (_CurrentComplexFilter.Right == null)
            {
                _CurrentComplexFilter.Right = _CurrentSimpleFilter;
                _Filters.Add(_CurrentComplexFilter);
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        else
        {
            _Filters.Add(_CurrentSimpleFilter);
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }

    private string extraxtFieldValue(object value)
    {
        string fieldValue;
        if (value is DateTime)
            fieldValue = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        else if (value is string)
            fieldValue = value.ToString();
        else if (value.GetType().IsEnum)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else
        {
            // Not sure if this is the best way to do this or not but can't figure out how
            // else to get a variable value.

            // If we are here then we are dealing with a property, field, or variable.
            // This means we must extract the value from the object.
            // In order to do this we will rely on _CurrentMemberExpression
            if (_CurrentMemberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                fieldValue = value.GetType().GetProperty(_CurrentMemberExpression.Member.Name).GetValue(value, null).ToString();
            }
            else if (_CurrentMemberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                fieldValue = value.GetType().GetFields().First().GetValue(value).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        return fieldValue;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you'd like any more detail....

Thanks

Comment: are your filters always going to be Entity.Property for the left hand side of the binary op?

Comment: They will be properties or fields.

Comment: I see you accepted my answer on your other question, was my answer clear enough for you to integrate your QueryFilter classes in?

Comment: I didn't really see that until after I posted this question.  It does seem to be working.  It's odd though that what I was initially doing (not posted in the question) wasn't working.  Initially I was trying something very similar: Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(constantExpressionNode, typeof(object)).Compile().Invoke().

Comment: The reason that didn't work is because constantExpressionNode isn't always an expression which returns something of type "object".  The type will same as the field member which could be string/int/datetime etc.  Thats why I used the generic "Expression.Lambda" and generic delegates

Comment: @devlife let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2298/discussion-between-merickowa-and-devlife)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [an article about this very issue from Matt Warren](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx). He provides source for a class that does exactly this, with an explanation how does it do it. It's also included in [his IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in using a open source third party library to do this for you, you can check out [Expression Tree Serialization](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization). I believe it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Seeing as how the serializer will convert any LINQ expression down to an XElement, which then can be turned into an xml string across the wire, this seems to be exactly what the op is looking to do. If you could kindly point out what is lacking, I would be much obliged.

Comment: The way I read the question, he wants to convert the expression into a very specific form (the example is `"bankname = 'Bank 1' or bankname = 'Bank 2'"`), not some XML.

Comment: " The request is XML with a particular element containing a query string." To me it looked like he was trying to turn a query into a serialized xml string, which is what the library I pointed to does. Since it serializes and deserializes, and Expression has a .ToString() method that makes it more plain text, this was the closest I could think of.