# Linq.Expression GetValue in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

Question:

I have this C# program, that gets the value of field tablename of mytable.
And it works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace AttachObjectsCS
{


    static class Program
    {


        public class cmytable
        {
            public string tablename = "test";
        }


        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616638/access-the-value-of-a-member-expression
        private static object GetValue(System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression member)
        {
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression objectMember = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<object>> getterLambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);

            var getter = getterLambda.Compile();

            return getter();
        }


        public static void AddField<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> expr, string alias)
        {
            var body = ((System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)expr.Body);
            Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", body.Member.Name);


            object obj = GetValue(body);


            Console.WriteLine("Value is: {0}", obj);
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            if (false)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }


            cmytable mytable = new cmytable();

            AddField(() => mytable.tablename, "te");


            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } // End Sub Main 


    } // End Class Program


} // End Namespace AttachObjectsCS
```

Now I need the same functionality in VB.NET, but it fails.
Now since I'm aware that VB.NET and C# don't always use the same linq expression, I'm not surprised that I run into a problem here.

```
Module Program




    Public Class cmytable
        Public tablename As String = "test"
    End Class


    Public Sub AddField(Of T)(expr As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T)))
        Dim body = DirectCast(expr.Body, System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)
        Dim strName As String = body.Member.Name
        Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", strName)


        Dim obj As Object = GetValue(body)


        Console.WriteLine("Value is: {0}", obj)
    End Sub


    ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616638/access-the-value-of-a-member-expression '
    Private Function GetValue(member As System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression) As Object
        Dim objectMember As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(member, GetType(Object))
        Dim getterLambda As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of Object)) = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Object))(objectMember)


        Dim getter = getterLambda.Compile()

        Return getter()
    End Function



    Public Sub Main()

        Dim mytable As New cmytable

        AddField(Function() mytable.tablename)
    End Sub


End Module ' Program
```

The problem is in GetValue, and the problem is that I don't seem to have the proper objectMember.

Here the debug output for the expressions:

```
CS objectMember = {Convert(value(AttachObjectsCS.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).mytable.tablename)}
VB objectMember = {Convert(value(AttachObjects.Program+_Closure$__1).$VB$Local_mytable.tablename)}

CS getterLambda = {() => Convert(value(AttachObjectsCS.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).mytable.tablename)}
VB getterLambda = {() => Convert(value(AttachObjects.Program+_Closure$__1).$VB$Local_mytable.tablename)}
```

My guess would be that the problem is the `$VB$Local_` in `$VB$Local_mytable.tablename`

Now I'm wondering what I have to change for this to work in VB.NET. 
Anybody knows / has a clue ?

**Edit:**
Ah, the problem seems to be caused by "Option Infer Off" in the project wide settings. 
So the the question alters and becomes: How to do this with "Option Infer Off" ?

Comment: Your VB code works fine for me.

Comment: Both run fine for me also (VS 2008, x64)

Comment: @svick: Ah, very interesting. That leaves one possible reason. Tested hypothesis & found right --> The problem is caused by "Option Infer Off" in the project-wide settings. Now the new question is what do i need to do to get it working with infer = off.

Comment: Leave Option Infer on?  Its nice to have the compiler do the work for you :)

Comment: @Pondidum: No, because it's not so nice to meet some other errors at runtime instead of compile-time. It's already bad enough I have to disable option strict because I (have to) use oledb-com-objects (which requires late binding --> which in turn requires option strict off).

Comment: @Quandary I don;t know much about VB, but I don't see why would `Option Infer On` do that. And you should probably set `Option Strict On` globally and turn it off only in the files where you actually need it.

Comment: @svick: You're right. Good advice. I have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with expression trees (which would be easier to spot if you bothered to include the error you're getting).

You have `Option Infer Off` and `Option Strict Off` and the following code:

```
Dim getter = getterLambda.Compile()

Return getter()
```

which throws `MissingMemberException`:

> No default member found for type 'Func(Of Object)'.

The problem is that `()` is here interpreted as invoking the default member and not invoking a delegate, because `getter` is typed as `Object`. To work around that, you can specify the type of the variable:

```
Dim getter As Func(Of Object) = getterLambda.Compile()

Return getter()
```

or you can use more verbose syntax for invoking a delegate:

```
Dim getter = getterLambda.Compile()

Return getter.Invoke()
```

Comment: Oh crap, this just demonstrates how wrong it is to use "Option Strict Off" (and "Option Infer On" with var in C#). Thanks !