# how can i print the name of the variables contained in the collection?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a collection containing variables I want to print the names of the variable in this collection

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyisL.png)

The method that returns the type is working, I couldn't find the name
How can I create a function to do this where it says GetName() below

```
var collection = new List<object> { b,sb,shrt,ushrt,i,ui,lng,ulng,f,d,dec,c,str,b1,b2,b3,o1,o2,o3,o4,dt };
    

foreach (object item in collection)
{
    
    Console.WriteLine("variable name : "+item.GetName() );
    Console.WriteLine("variable value: "+item);
    Console.WriteLine("variable type : "+ item.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("***************************** ");
}
```

Comment: The collection doesn't contain variables, it contains objects/values. As soon as you add an item to the collection, it doesn't care where it originally came from. If for whatever reason you need to maintain the names, consider using a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: I would like to know why you want to do this? What's the purpose of knowing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows iterating a collection of type `Object` and we know for sure that class `Object` *does* have a `GetType()` method and `_doesn't`_ have a `GetName()` method or `Name` property. But the `item` in your collection most likely isn't "really" an `object`, it's some class that (like every class) *inherits* `Object`. You seem confident that this unknown class *has* a `Name` property but even if the object type of `item` is completely unknown, you can use `System.Reflection` to print out the Name if it exists and an error readout if it doesn't.

Wrapping this reflection in an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) is of the easier ways to answer your question:

> [...]How can I create a function to do this where it says GetName()

```
static partial class Extensions
{
    public static string GetName(this object unk)
    {
        Type type = unk.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Name");
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return $"Error: Type '{type.Name}' does not have a Name property.";
        }
        else
        {
            return $"{propertyInfo.GetValue(unk)}";
        }
    }
}
```

---

**MOCK**

With the extension in place, you can now use the syntax shown in your post.

```
var collection = new object []
{
    new HasNameA(),
    new HasNameB(),
    new NoNameC(),
};

foreach (object item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("variable name : " + item.GetName());
    Console.WriteLine("variable value: " + item);
    Console.WriteLine("variable type : " + item.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("***************************** ");
}
```

[image: console]

Where:

```
class HasNameA
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "A";
    public object Value { get; set; } = 1;
    public override string ToString() => $"{Value}";
}
class HasNameB
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "B";
    public object Value { get; set; } = "Hello";
    public override string ToString() => $"{Value}";
}
class NoNameC
{
    public object Value { get; set; } = Math.PI;
    public override string ToString() => $"{Value}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list does not contain the variables.

It contains either:

- the values variable or
- the references that the variable points to

Please see [Value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

What you are trying to achieve is not possible without significant changes to the code.

The best I could do is the following.

Result

```
b: True, Boolean
sb: , StringBuilder
shrt: 7, Int16
```

Code

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

bool b = true;
StringBuilder sb = new ();
short shrt = 7;


var l = new List<(string Name,object V)> { Get(() => b), Get(() => sb), Get(() => shrt) };

foreach(var x in l)
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name}: {x.V}, {x.V.GetType().Name}" );

static (string Name ,T V) Get<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616638/access-the-value-of-a-member-expression
    // with modifications
    MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(expressionBody);
    var getter = lambda.Compile();
    var v =  getter();

    return (expressionBody.Member.Name, v);
}
```