# Get FieldExpression value in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm new to Expressions in C#, and I'm trying to create a transformer from `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to a SQL Where clause. I managed to do so when the provided expression looks like this

```cs
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> predicate = p => p.Price > 100 && p.Category == "Electronics" && p.PriceTotal >= 200;
```

In the above example, I can break the expression to Member Expression and Constant Expression and create the equivalent SQL Where clause. Now I'm trying to do the same for this -

```cs
public void GetWhereCluase(string categoryName)
{
    Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate = p => p.Category == categoryName && p.PriceTotal >= 200;
    GetClause(predicate);
}
```

But this time, the Right side is a FieldExpression and I don't know how I can get the actual value.

I tried compiling the `Func<T,bool>` but without luck.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616638/access-the-value-of-a-member-expression

Comment: Why do you think you need a FieldExpression? There's no field to access here, just a variable whose value is baked into your delegate. So you still want a `ConstantExpression` providing the value of `categeoryName`, something like `Expression.Constant(categoryName)` instead of `Expression.Constant("Electronics")`.

Comment: @freakish thanks for the link, the second answer there did the trick